Java Unchecked Cast in Generic Method While Validating and Returning a Specific Implementation of an Interface
Question:
I am working on a system where I manage connectors(Connector<RQ, RS>) identified by keys (ChannelKey<RQ, RS>). Each ChannelKey maps to a specific Connector implementation, and I want to retrieve the connector using the key while ensuring type safety.
Here's the relevant code:
public <RQ, RS> Optional<Class<? extends Connector<RQ, RS>>> get(final ChannelKey<RQ, RS> key) {
    final Optional<Connector<?, ?>> connector = findConnector(key.getChannelName());
    return connector.flatMap(prev -> validateToGet(prev, key));
}


private <RQ, RS> Optional<Class<? extends Connector<RQ, RS>>> validateToGet(Connector<?, ?> prev, ChannelKey<RQ, RS> key) {

    Class<? extends Connector<RQ, RS>> targetClass = moduleProvider
            .getConnectorFactory(key.getChannelName())
            .flatMap(factory -> Optional.ofNullable(factory.getConnectorClass()))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Connector class not found for channel: " + key.getChannelName()));

    Class<?> receivedClass = prev.getClass();

    if (targetClass.isAssignableFrom(receivedClass)) {
        Class<? extends Connector<RQ, RS>> castedClass = (Class<? extends Connector<RQ, RS>>) receivedClass;
        return Optional.of(castedClass);
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}


public Optional<Connector<?, ?>> findConnector(String name) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(runningChannels.get(name));
}


public static final ChannelKey<Request, Response> BLUE = new BaseChannelKey<>("Blue", BlueRequest.class, BlueResponse.class);

Problem:
When I try to cast receivedClass to (Class<? extends Connector<RQ, RS>>) in the validateToGet method, I get an unchecked cast warning. The functionality I am aiming for is as When calling get(ChannelKey.BLUE), I want the result to be an Optional<BlueConnector<BlueRequest, BlueResponse>, where BlueConnector is a specific implementation of Connector<Request, Response>.
However, this cast generates a warning, and I want to ensure that the implementation is both type-safe and warning-free. For context:

Connector<RQ, RS> is an interface with multiple implementations.
I need to validate that the received connector matches the expected type defined by the ChannelKey and then cast it to the appropriate type.

Alternative Attempts:
I also tried the following aprouch, but it required explicit generic types during the method call, which I want to avoid:
public <RQ, RS> Connector<RQ, RS> find(ChannelKey<RQ, RS> key) {
    return (Connector<RQ, RS>) runningChannels.get(key.getChannelName());
}

For example:
Connector<Request, Response> blueConnector = channelManager.find(ChannelKeys.BLUE);

This works, but it is not the behavior I want. Instead, I want to use solely the key to deduce the expected connector class.
Question:

How can I resolve the unchecked cast warning in validateToGet while ensuring type safety?
Is there a better design pattern or approach to achieve this functionality where the key determines the connector type, and the result is returned as the correct generic type?


Class should be kept as far away from generics as possible. You'll have to start with writing that out (use a Factory instead; Factory is the solution to the problem: "I'd like to define the concept of a type where the type itself has certain properties, such as a static method, or a constructor with certain arguments)".

Which java version do you use?  Did you try to check the cast (via instance of)?



How can I resolve the unchecked cast warning in validateToGet while ensuring type safety?


You can't with the data structures you're presently using.  Your type parameterization is not sufficient for Java to validate the safety of your cast at compile time. (And if it were, then you wouldn't need a cast in the first place.)
Your storage for connectors is apparently runningChannels, a Map<String, Connector<?, ?>> or similar.  When you retrieve a connector from there, Java has no basis for validating a narrower type than Connector<?, ?>.  Any cast implementing such a conversion is necessarily unchecked.
Note that the alternative presented in the question is not an exception.  Its cast is still unchecked.


Is there a better design pattern or approach to achieve this functionality where the key determines the connector type, and the result is returned as the correct generic type?


Occasionally, the best choice is to accept an unchecked cast.  This may be one of those times.
The kind of problem you describe comes up from time to time, where a map-like data structure's overall key and value types are broad, but the keys' specific types convey information about their corresponding values' specific types.  The problem is that those key / value type correspondences are a characteristic only of the use of such a data structure. They are not captured by its type, and therefore they cannot be statically checked or validated.  If you cannot abide unchecked casts, then you need to avoid data structures whose own types do not provide all the information you need about the types of the items within.
One possibility might be simply to dispense with the <RQ, RS> parameterization of your Connectors.  It's not clear from your example code whether that's actually doing anything for you.  Or in a similar vein, you may be able simply to work with the retrieved Connectors as Connector<?, ?>.  If neither of those is viable for you then pragmatically, you probably need to bite the bullet and accept an unchecked cast, as other alternatives, if available, would likely involve major changes in the design of your application.
